# Referenced script files not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have six script files that I would load and use on a regular basis. My thought was to have one master script that loaded all six so I just referenced the master whenever I wanted.

So I use the following to load the other files:

```
var jqmouse = document.createElement("script");
jqmouse.type = "text/javascript";
jqmouse.src = "../fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel.3.0.6.pack.js";
document.body.appendChild(jqmouse);
```

The trouble is that the files are showing 404 in IE & Chrome debug console. Double checked with Fiddler and they are not being found???

[image]

I have checked and double checked. Either my eyes / brain is confused or something is going on that I am not understanding.

Also I can't add script to a master file or other such method as I am working with a 3rd party.

Thanks for the assistance

---

Solved....once I corrected directory structure from the html page not the scripts it worked...**FACE PALM**

Comment: Hello , what do u see on Head tag in Browser? Click on that link ,Does it open?

Comment: What is the relevant absolute path to script on server? What is the URL currently browser trying to reach? Be aware, using relative path, path will be relative to current page client side

Comment: @PratikJoshi Do you mean like this line here:  <script type="text/javascript" src=".../scripts/fancyboxmaster.js?ver=-1421142338" id="../scripts/fancyboxmaster.js?ver=-1421142338"></script>

Comment: Then on clicking on that link .Does it open?

Comment: You need to make the URLs relative to the HTML document, not the other scripts.

Comment: @Quentin...ohhhhh that might be what everyone is trying to get through the wall of rocks I have for a brain....but then wouldn't Amit Joki's answer have worked???...cause it didn't.

Comment: @PratikJoshi yes it opens in the debug sources tab

Comment: Then its loading dude .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use relative url to the root of the website.:

```
jqmouse.src = "/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel.3.0.6.pack.js";
```

Using the above url works all the time, whereas `../` is dependant on the folder structure.

Comment: That's not an absolute URL, even it could fix OP's issue, just saying... ;)

Comment: and it didn't fix it.

Comment: @A.Wolff, sorry, I don't know what is the name for the url, I'm using ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki That's still a relative path but relative to same level folder as current page EDIT: congrats for your 10k+ on SO :)

Comment: @A.Wolff, I've updated and hoping that I've used the correct term